# Which are recipes for "rolled fondant"?

Tags: cake, sugar, resources, decorating

I'm looking for recipe about rolled fondant for cake decoration.
I tried to search for it thought questions inside stackexchange, but i found nothing about (i'm probably non good researcher in english! I trust in you! :D ).

Thank's a lot! :)

Comment: I am sorry, but recipe requests are explicitely off-topic on our site. See the [faq] for details. If you find a recipe somewhere and it doesn't come out right, you can return with a description of your problem and we will be happy to help you make it right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one recipe:

http://www.food.com/recipe/rolled-fondant-247561

I cannot speak to its quality.  I would stay away from any recipe calling for marshmallow fluff, however--at least as fondant.

You can also purchase fondant, should you so choose, from some internet retailers or retail stores.